# How to have a visual indicator for the hyperref target in PDFLaTeX

Tags: hyperref, pdftex

I want to be able to  link to an item within a PDFLaTeX document and have the linked item pointed out by some indicator (perhaps a flashing arrow or something similar) when I land in its page.

So for example if I link to a paragraph and follow the link then I want to be taken to its page, where the entire page shows up, and the corresponding paragraph is pointed out by some visual means (instead of the page rolling up to the location of the linked item).

Is this possible?

Comment: Something like a `folder preview` on mouse-over?

Comment: Hupfer: No, not a preview. I click, go the linked item page, on that page the location of the item I am linking to is pointed out by  say a flashing arrow.

Comment: I am confused by `flashing arrow`. Perhaps you should add an image of a similar feature

Comment: Any indicator would do,  anything like a  -->  to draw the attention of the reader to a specific portion of a page (while showing the whole page). This is essentially a "cursor" for the reader.

Comment: I know you can display hyperref targets in color.  The first question is whether PDF supports something useful, then can you access this feature through hyperref.